How to Avoid Granting PipeAccessRights.CreateNewInstance to User Without NamedPipeServerStreamAcl.Create Throwing UnauthorizedAccessException
I've seen similar questions addressing the issue of creating a NamedPipeServerStream with security configurations throwing UnauthorizedAccessException.
The problem lies in creating multiple instances of pipes: .NET raises the exception when the client attempts to create another instance of the pipe when they don't have the permission to do so. The "solution" is to simply allow the users to create new pipe instances by adding PipeAccessRights.CreateNewInstance the user's rights.
This seemingly reputable user indicates that this is bad practice and is "probably a security hole."
Why is this a potential security hole, and how can I properly grant the creation of multiple instances when needed? I want to be able to create instances across a network.
